# How to find a memory leak in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, memory-leaks

I've got a Windows 7 32bit laptop that keeps running low in RAM. 
How can I figure out what is causing the memory to leak?

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ ===========     ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0             24 K
SYSTEM                           4 Services                   0            880 K
smss.exe                       400 Services                   0            200 K
csrss.exe                      640 Services                   0      1,732 K
wininit.exe                    708 Services                   0        428 K
csrss.exe                      716 Console                    1     14,068 K
services.exe                   760 Services                   0      4,216 K
lsass.exe                      768 Services                   0      6,012 K
lsm.exe                        776 Services                   0      1,452 K
svchost.exe                    900 Services                   0      4,416 K
vsserv.exe                     956 Services                   0    218,120 K
winlogon.exe                  1000 Console                    1        740 K
ibmpmsvc.exe                  1356 Services                   0        740 K
LPlatSvc.exe                  1392 Services                   0        704 K
nvvsvc.exe                    1456 Services                   0      1,332 K
nvwmi.exe                     1480 Services                   0        504 K
svchost.exe                   1520 Services                   0      4,336 K
svchost.exe                   1620 Services                   0     12,420 K
svchost.exe                   1668 Services                   0      7,716 K
svchost.exe                   1712 Services                   0      3,376 K
svchost.exe                   1744 Services                   0     13,340 K
svchost.exe                   1852 Services                   0      2,600 K
igfxCUIService.exe            1964 Services                   0      1,624 K
SbieSvc.exe                    376 Services                   0        576 K
nvxdsync.exe                  1272 Console                    1      2,348 K
nvvsvc.exe                    1496 Console                    1      1,268 K
nvwmi.exe                      372 Console                    1        872 K
WUDFHost.exe                  2096 Services                   0        560 K
WUDFHost.exe                  2156 Services                   0        708 K
explorer.exe                  2320 Console                    1     28,264 K
svchost.exe                   2464 Services                   0      7,240 K
spoolsv.exe                   2636 Services                   0      4,568 K
svchost.exe                   2684 Services                   0      3,644 K
taskhost.exe                  2768 Console                    1      5,488 K
svchost.exe                   2852 Services                   0      4,288 K
TPHKSVC.exe                   2952 Services                   0      1,112 K
tphkload.exe                  3004 Services                   0      1,280 K
LPlatSvc.exe                  3204 Console                    1        656 K
tpnumlkd.exe                  3212 Console                    1      4,432 K
svchost.exe                   3264 Services                   0      1,548 K
WmiPrvSE.exe                  3272 Services                   0      2,016 K
mDNSResponder.exe             3296 Services                   0      1,156 K
svchost.exe                   3364 Services                   0      1,772 K
EvtEng.exe                    3448 Services                   0      2,340 K
FsUsbExService.Exe            3576 Services                   0        460 K
hasplms.exe                   3752 Services                   0      3,672 K
svchost.exe                   3888 Services                   0        676 K
ibtsiva.exe                   3964 Services                   0        496 K
bdagent.exe                   3972 Console                    1      6,424 K
imdsksvc.exe                  4044 Services                   0        316 K
clipx.exe                     4060 Console                    1        628 K
micmute.exe                   2268 Services                   0        848 K
lvvsst.exe                    2696 Services                   0        748 K
rundll32.exe                  2984 Console                    1      3,976 K
MIGService.exe                3172 Services                   0        876 K
ReflectUI.exe                 3076 Console                    1        940 K
unsecapp.exe                   188 Services                   0      1,388 K
SynciosDeviceService.exe      1500 Console                    1      2,340 K
MacriumService.exe            3660 Services                   0      3,500 K
virtscrl.exe                  3028 Console                    1      1,268 K
rundll32.exe                  3824 Console                    1        572 K
MNSFramework.exe              3704 Services                   0        644 K
svchost.exe                   4188 Services                   0        384 K
TpShocks.exe                  4244 Console                    1        748 K
ReflectMonitor.exe            4264 Console                    1      1,552 K
svchost.exe                   4284 Services                   0        464 K
ProductAgentService.exe       4324 Services                   0      4,976 K
UnlockerAssistant.exe         4396 Console                    1        716 K
PSIService.exe                4420 Services                   0        436 K
WmiPrvSE.exe                  4432 Services                   0      6,576 K
PsiService_2.exe              4488 Services                   0      3,776 K
TPONSCR.exe                   4496 Console                    1        956 K
SynTPEnh.exe                  4504 Console                    1      6,268 K
shtctky.exe                   4524 Console                    1        888 K
NPSAgent.exe                  4612 Console                    1        800 K
QBCFMonitorService.exe        4624 Services                   0      6,092 K
CCleaner.exe                  4664 Console                    1     10,264 K
DeeEnEs.exe                   4744 Console                    1      1,148 K
SynTPHelper.exe               4800 Console                    1        992 K
QBIDPService.exe              4920 Services                   0      1,216 K
ScanToPCActivationApp.exe     5000 Console                    1      2,388 K
RegSrvc.exe                   5148 Services                   0        616 K
ss_conn_service.exe           5176 Services                   0        476 K
TeamViewer_Service.exe        5212 Services                   0      6,068 K
updatesrv.exe                 5360 Services                   0      5,652 K
SbieCtrl.exe                  5388 Console                    1      2,192 K
winvnc.exe                    5428 Services                   0        592 K
taskeng.exe                   5632 Console                    1      1,096 K
IconSaver.exe                 5644 Console                    1        604 K
valWBFPolicyService.exe       5740 Services                   0        512 K
svchost.exe                   5808 Services                   0      1,832 K
unsecapp.exe                  5832 Console                    1      2,104 K
qbupdate.exe                  5972 Console                    1      9,232 K
mini_WMCore.exe               6016 Services                   0      1,448 K
androidnotifier.exe           6088 Console                    1        980 K
winvnc.exe                    4100 Console                    1      2,920 K
PresentationFontCache.exe     5620 Services                   0      1,196 K
RemindMe.exe                  6180 Console                    1      1,968 K
svchost.exe                   6280 Services                   0        580 K
Spell Catcher.exe             6448 Console                    1     15,920 K
svchost.exe                   6504 Services                   0        520 K
TeamViewer.exe                6696 Console                    1     11,992 K
igfxEM.exe                    6744 Console                    1      1,012 K
igfxHK.exe                    6780 Console                    1        544 K
SearchIndexer.exe             7028 Services                   0      7,228 K
HPNetworkCommunicator.exe     7252 Console                    1      1,156 K
RtHDVBg.exe                   7424 Console                    1        516 K
SynTPLpr.exe                  7588 Console                    1        632 K
adb.exe                       7652 Console                    1      1,684 K
tv_w32.exe                    7836 Console                    1        784 K
SCHTASK.EXE                   7856 Console                    1        848 K
wmpnetwk.exe                  8048 Services                   0      5,756 K
bdredline.exe                  416 Services                   0        812 K
jhi_service.exe               2764 Services                   0        828 K
LMS.exe                        700 Services                   0      7,080 K
ICM-Service.exe               4080 Services                   0      3,508 K
PWMDBSVC.exe                  2396 Services                   0      1,064 K
taskhost.exe                   852 Console                    1      4,132 K
dwm.exe                       6924 Console                    1      2,964 K
taskmgr.exe                   7568 Console                    1     10,700 K
salamand.exe                  5936 Console                    1     31,696 K
salmon.exe                    5628 Console                    1      3,548 K
cmd.exe                       5508 Console                    1      2,912 K
conhost.exe                   8024 Console                    1      5,032 K
tasklist.exe                  4368 Console                    1      5,684 K
```

Thank you,

Docfxit

Comment: Well, bit defender is using the most memory. That doesn't mean it is leaking memory though. You would have to look at memory over time.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of a memory leak? Memory being used is not evidence of a leak. Do you have any actual symptoms? What makes you think it's running low on RAM?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s memory usage view. // Also, the AV scanner using ~200 MiB of memory is not abnormal. In fact, 200 MiB isn’t even a significant amount in modern systems

Comment: post picture of [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) and task manager so that we can see if you actually have an issue or if you misunderstood memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

click the `Mem usage` so it will sort the list from high usage to low usage, then look at the top who consuming more RAM.

based on the list you provided, `vsserv.exe` has the most Mem Usage which appeared to be the main bitdefender process that provides continuous real-time protection against a wide range of malware threats and online attacks.

> If you notice a significant slowdown and Task Manager indicates that the vsserv.exe process stays at 100% CPU usage, follow these steps:
>
> 1) Set Bitdefender On-Access scanning on Default level:
>
> a. Open the Bitdefender window.
>
> b. Click the Settings button on the upper toolbar.
>
> c. In the Settings Overview window, select Antivirus.
>
> d. In the Antivirus Settings window, select the Shield tab.
>
> e. Set On-access scanning on Default.
>
> Check if your system performance is improved. If you are satisfied with the system speed, you may keep the default protection level because it ensures good protection against malware, with minor impact on system performance.
>
> 2) In case the system still runs slowly, temporarly turn off the Active Virus Control :
>
> a. Open the Bitdefenderwindow.
>
> b. Click the Settings button on the upper toolbar.
>
> c. In the Settings Overview window, select Antivirus.
>
> d. In the Antivirus Settings window, select the Shield tab.
>
> e. Click the switch to turn off Active Virus Control.
>
> Check if your system performance is improved with the Active Virus Control disabled.

Source: [Bitdefender Support | vsserv.exe](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/what-is-the-vsserv-exe-process-1116.html)

Comment: I went head and quoted the article for you.  Please cite and quote your sources in the future including using valid formatting code in your contributions.

Comment: sorry, forgot about that xD

Answer (score 0):

It appears the vsserv.exe is using a significant amount of memory. I believe this process is a BitDefender component.

If the amount of memory of the computer is lower (not stated in the question), it can cause an impact.

BitDefender is highly customizable. You have to consult the manual and reduce the workload by optimizing the configuration.

To troubleshoot memory issues. you can utilize the following tools.

- Task Manager
- Resource monitor
- Performance monitor (Advanced)
- [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Sometimes malware and malfunctioning applications also cause high memory utilization. Sometimes a malfunctioning memory module can cause a low amount of memory.

Comment: I found LMS.exe is using 25% of my CPU.  I found a post in the Lenovo forum that said:    This version of LMS.exe seems to have a bug that causes it to misbehave when an internet connection is blocked.  It goes into a loop using 25% CPU and also fails to release memory correctly on each cycle round the loop.  Task manager shows ca 25% CPU usage and increasing memory usage - icons may disappear off the desktop etc as the problem builds up and eventually stalls the PC.  I would like to post two snap shots as requested but I don't see how.

Comment: This PC is not used in a corporate environment.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/pvlkx22vb/

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/85euf2bav/

Comment: @Docfxit Super User is not a forum. Please reply to comments in the same location. If applicable, use `@username` to trigger notifications. If additional information has been requested, [update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1306695/edit).

Comment: This LMS.exe is an Intel component. If this is running and utilizing the CPU, you have to see if the Intel Management Interface service is running. You can disable these from starting up using the Task Manager > Startup tab. Also, check the system tray. You can also use the services.msc control panel to disable it. @Docfxit